# Have trouble with HTML::Template

Tags: perl, templates

```
foreach $result (keys %{$results_ref}){
    $source = $results_ref->{$result}->{abs_path};
    $source =~ s#/home/##;
    print "<div><img src=\"$source\" /></div>";
}
```

It seems [`HTML:Template`](http://search.cpan.org/~samtregar/HTML-Template-2.6/Template.pm) only support basic syntax. How can I do logic like above with it?

**UPDATE**

An arrayref to hash is not always enough ,consider the following example:

```
print $hash{LEFT};
foreach $i ($hash{START}..$hash{END}){
    if($pager == $i){
        print "<span>$i<span>";
    }
    else {
        print "<span><a href=\"/index.pl?page=$i\">$i</a></span>";
    }
```

How would you do it with arrayref to hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly I think you are looking for the `TMPL_LOOP` tag.

Build an array of hashes, and pass that as a variable to `param()` call. Then use `TMPL_LOOP` to build what you were doing in the `foreach`.

```
 my $sources_loop = [];
 foreach $result (keys %$results_ref) {
    $source = $results_ref->{$result}->{abs_path};
    $source =~ s#/home/##;
    push(@$sources_loop, { source => $source });
 }

 $template->param(sourcesloop => $sources_loop);
```

Then in the template:

```
 <!--TMPL_LOOP NAME="sourcesloop"-->
     <div><img src="<!--TMPL_VAR NAME="source"-->" /></div>
 <!--/TMPL_LOOP-->
```

**EDIT** (response to Update):

Again, if I understand correctly, then I would use different keys to drive the logic of the template loop. You can have `TMPL_IF` as part of `TMPL_LOOP`

```
my $sources_loop = [];
foreach $i ($hash{START}..$hash{END}){
    if($pager == $i){
         push(@$sources_loop, { lone => $i });
    }
    else {
        push(@$sources_loop, { linked => $i });
    }
}

$template->param(sourcesloop => $sourcesloop, hashleft => $hash{LEFT});
```

Template:

```
 <!--TMPL_VAR NAME="hashleft"-->
 <!--TMPL_LOOP NAME="sourcesloop"-->
     <!--TMPL_IF NAME="lone"--><span><!--TMPL_VAR NAME="lone"-->"</span><!--/TMPL_IF-->
     <!--TMPL_IF NAME="linked"--><span><a href="/index.pl?page=<!--TMPL_VAR NAME="linked"-->"><!--TMPL_VAR NAME="linked"--></a></span><!--/TMPL_IF-->
 <!--/TMPL_LOOP-->
```

**EDIT**: updated to include $hash{LEFT}

Comment: So the only option is to pass an array reference?

Comment: HTML::Template expects an arrayref of anonymous hashes for template loops. That's just the way it is designed. Also it's worth noting that the anonymous hash can have many keys too.

Comment: But in some cases I just want to pass hash reference instead of arrayref of hashes..

Comment: You want to use a hashref instead? For what reason? I'm a bit lost as to how you want to use that hash? if you have a simple hash you can pass that to the param() call with `param(%hash)`. But note that the contents of that hash must be of the right format for param() to be parse it correctly (i.e hashes of hashes will not parse properly, and a key with an array reference will be treated as a template loop)

Comment: I've updated again with another case ,how would you do it in `HTML::Template`?

Comment: ,do you really feel comfortable with such design?

Comment: @new_perl let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1170/discussion-between-drav-sloan-and-new-perl)